# Why does the Alloy API solution's ".next()" method keep returning the same solution? Can I force it to return the next unique solution?

Tags: alloy

Can anyone explain why the Alloy API solution's ".next()" might return the exact same solution ad infinitum?  It doesn't always, but when it does, I get stuck in an infinite loop.  Is there a way to get the next unique solution?

Comment: It should stop producing solutions after a while. Could you share your model and the version of Alloy you are on?

Comment: The version is 6.1.  I'm working on a project that I don't want to share publicly, but this behavior occurs for all of the models I've developed (and they're very different from each other).  Typically, the .next() will eventually stop, but even when it does, I get many copies of the same solutions over and over, wasting processor time for my application.

Comment: Correction - it seems that the Analyzer is finding new solutions eventually, but only after finding the exact same solution many times.  Wondering if there is some type of symmetry involved where it's arriving at the same solution from many different angles...